# Place a footer with Content positioned as absolute

Tags: html, css, footer

I have a wrapper class that contains all the content on the web page. the problem is if the content is absolutely placed, it eats my footer. I have to place the content as absolute positioned.

It seems like the footer doesnot recognize that the content is absolute. Heres my code

```
<style>

* {
    margin: 0;
    }
    html, body {
    height: 100%;
    }
    .wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -4em;
    }
    .footer, .push {

    height: 4em;
    }
 </style>
 </head>

<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<img src="activity/Chrysanthemum.jpg" style="z-index: 1; position:absolute; width: 420px; height: 400px; left: 100px;top:260px; ">
<div class="push">
</div>
</div>
<div class="footer" >copyrights</div>
</body>
```

If I change the image style by removing the `position:absolute` property , everything looks normal. so my question is how can we place the footer at the bottom with absolute positioned contents?

Comment: Google 'css sticky footer' and you'll find some good ways to do it

Comment: Seemed he did that Moin.
I see the problem is the only content is absolute img on wrapper, I think that's is a problem.

Comment: yea i did try the `www.cssstickyfooter.com` method but its nt working either! is it even possible to stick a footer at the bottom with absolute contents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated answer, regarding comment.
As I mentioned at my previous answer, this effect cannot be achieved using pure CSS. So, I will show the JavaScript approach. Add relevant IDs (see **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4ja2V/1/)**), and add the following code at the end of your body. This code snippet will resize your wrapper when necessary.
Note: When the page is smaller than the window's height, the page wrapper will still take the full height, because it's not possible to distinguish a height change by an absolutely positioned element.

```
<script>
(function(){
    var wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper");
    var height = document.documentElement.scrollHeight;
    wrapper.style.height = height + "px";
})();
</script>
```

---

*Previous answer:*
The issue is caused by the fact that absolutely-positioned elements do not affect the height/width of their parent.

To fix your code, apply the following CSS (only showing relevant CSS, updated postfixed by descriptive comments). **Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4ja2V/**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0; /* Get rid off the padding */
}
.wrapper {
    position: relative; /* Necessary to properly deal with absolutely positioned
                           child elements. */
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto 4em; /* So that the content is visible when scrolled down*/
}
.footer {
    height: 4em;
    position: fixed; /* Positions your footer at a fixed position in the window*/
    bottom: 0; /* At the bottom of the window*/
}
```

You were using a negative bottom-margin for `.wrapper`, which caused the element to "eat" the footer. When you're using absolutely poisitioned inner elements, there's no reliable pure-CSS method to get the real width/height of the `.wrapper` element. Hence the appearance of `position:fixed`.

The footer is defined to have a height of `4em`. Because the footer is positioned at a fixed position (ie, the element won't move when scrolling down), it's necessary to apply an additional margin at the bottom of the wrapper element.

Comment: thanks alot for the answer...i am sorry if the question was a bit misleading. i saw the fiddle and what i am trying to do is to place the `copyright` text under the red box in ur demo. so in short if there is a vertical scroll bar, the footer shud be at the bottom, and in case of no scroll bar the footer shud be at the bottom of viewport.

Answer (score 0):

give your footer a fixed hight and then in your absolute class, do

```
bottom: heightOfYourFooter + 5px;
```

Comment: its not working...luks like the `bottom` property has no effect when used with `top` and `left` properties